# Overload resolution of inherited template function

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I would expect the call to `f(signed{})` to be resolved during overload resolution as overload `f(std::integral auto)` is included in the overload set of `f` by use of the using-declaration `using b::f`. The call to `f(unsigned{})` is resolved due to `f(std::unsigned_integral auto)` being more constrained than `f(std::integral auto)`, as `std::unsigned_integral` subsumes `std::integral`.

However, MSVC blatantly rejects this code. Which paragraph of the C++20 standard allows for the call of `f(signed{})` to be resolved?

```cpp
#include <concepts>

struct b { void f(std::integral auto); };
struct d : b { using b::f; void f(std::unsigned_integral auto); };

static_assert(requires { d{}.f(signed{}); }); // clang ok, gcc ok, msvc nope
static_assert(requires { d{}.f(unsigned{}); }); // all ok
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1e4d5M4Ws)

---

MSVC's error message:

```cpp
<source>(6): error C2672: 'd::f': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(4): note: could be 'void d::f(_T0)'
<source>(6): note: the associated constraints are not satisfied
<source>(4): note: the concept 'std::unsigned_integral<signed int>' evaluated to
false
C:/data/msvc/14.38.33133/include\concepts(76): note: the constraint was not
satisfied
<source>(6): error C2607: static assertion failed
```

Answer (score 4):

We can actually address this question without dealing with constraints at all, which is simpler.  Consider

```
struct X {
  template<class> void f();
};
struct Y : X {
  using X::f;
  template<int> void f();
};
void use(Y y) {
  y.f<void>();
  y.f<1>();
}
```

C++20 as published says this is **invalid**, because the template defined in `X` is too similar to the one defined in `Y` and so the *using-declaration* ignores it ([namespace.udecl]/14).  (Your example is equivalent: the template heads are the only difference in the templates' signatures.)  This doesn't make any sense, though, because you can certainly declare both of those templates in any one scope and even usefully distinguish them (as in `use`).  Accordingly, [P1787R6](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html) **changed** the *using-declaration* rule to additionally consider template heads (in what is now /11, via a new general term "corresponds" used in several places for consistency).

However, compilers have not yet implemented many of the changes in P1787R6, so the current status is still that [GCC and ICC accept this, but Clang and MSVC do not](https://www.godbolt.org/z/6r3G1vE5M).  (Clang and GCC pretty frequently implement the letter and the spirit of the law, respectively.)

Comment: Well, that's rather surprising. I guess this is yet another reason to prefer to write member functions as free (friend) functions instead, whenever possible. But what is the deal with P1787R6? Can it be regarded as a defect report that has already been accepted and should be in effect for any complete implementation of the C++20 standard? I've happened to stumble upon another post of yours where you make the same comment about P1787R6 not being implemented yet, which was from 3 years ago or so.

Comment: @303: All bug fixes deliberately included in P1787R6 (as opposed to the specification improvements that merely made things say what we already politely understood them to mean) are considered "defect reports" (which means that they ought to be applied in all language modes).  However, I suspect this particular case was never recognized as a bug in the first place, so either we have to interpret the change as having introduced a defect in the standard or (preferably) interpret it as having "discovered" bugs in certain compilers.  By all means file a compiler bug and we'll see what happens.